# crontab condition, if a file size is more than 5000K than send an email

Tags: email, find, conditional-statements, cron

I have this incomplete command:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/domain/folder/ -name '*.flv' -size +5000k && /bin/mail -s "The file is available!" "my@address.com" > /dev/null
```

I'm not able to insert a conditional, if the file is more than 5000k it must send mail, else no.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` always returns an exit code of 0 except if there was something wrong. Therefore you have to use something else to generate an appropriate exit code (!=0) that can be used with `&&`. I would suggest `grep`, e.g.:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/domain/folder/ -name '*.flv' -size +5000k | grep flv && /bin/mail -s "The file is available!" "my@address.com" > /dev/null
```

If grep detects a line containing the string `flv` in the output of `find` it returns 0, otherwise 1. The `mail` command will only be executed on exit code 0 of `grep`.